# how can I convert the unix date into a specified date in snowflake?

Tags: sql, datetime, format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how can I convert the unix date into a specified date mentioned below in snowflake

unix date = 96227   expected output = 1996-08-14

I have tried using below query in snowflake

```
select cast(to_timestamp(1900000+96227) as date) as "effDate"
```

but both the above query and the unix converter online gives me the below result--

[image]

how can i construct a query in snowflake that gives me 1996-08-14, what number should I add while converting it ?

Comment: Just to note that the date format you have there (year number plus day of year number e.g. YYDDD) is known as a "Ordinal date", also sometimes called a "Julian date" although that term has several definitions. It's not a "unix date" - unix dates and times are measured in the number of seconds elapsed in the unix epoch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to answer from Gordon, and maybe simpler to manage use the following:

```
Set UNIX_DATE='96227';
Select DATEADD(day,RIGHT($UNIX_DATE,3)-1,TRY_TO_DATE(LEFT($UNIX_DATE,2),'YY'));
```

**Note**: Two-digit year, controlled by the TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START session parameter, default is 1970, which matches Unix epoch.

Answer (score 1):

Your data format appears to be in the format YYDDD, where YY is the year minus 1900 and DDD is the day of the year.

So:

```
select date_from_parts(1900 + d / 1000, 1, 1) + (d % 1000 - 1) * interval '1 day'
from (values (96227)) v(d);
```

Comment: make_date function does not work in snowflake :( @GordonLinoff